# Does anyone know if there is a LaTeX package for writing in steno?

Tags: packages

I am currently studying realtime stenography, and in making my own review materials, I have come to a point where it would be VERY useful to use LaTeX to typeset in the particular typographic style used in publishing stenography...does anyone know where I could find a LaTeX package or template that would help me do this using, say, Scrivener as my text editor?

Comment: Related : http://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb30-3/tb96sarman.pdf

Comment: Try on-line system, which using METAFONT: http://home.tu-clausthal.de/~rzsjs/steno/Pitman.php

Comment: In addition to the comment by @percusse, another form of shorthand is presented in http://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb29-3/tb93sarman.pdf. A google search for "writing gregg shorthand latex" or "writing pitman shorthand latex" (without the quotation marks) should leads to additional information in the form of videos etc.

Comment: Considering LaTeX is open-source, that might explain why no-one has developed any secret codes.

Comment: Maybe this video helps? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3gE5N0epdg

Comment: As far as I know, no such package exists.  It might be possible to write one if you tell us which of [the many systems (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorthand) you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if steno is related to Pitman shorthand, but you might want to check out the manual if it is of use to you: http://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb30-3/tb96sarman.pdf